# Can I reduce "that corresponds" to "corresponding"?

Tags: difference, alternatives, reduced-relative-clauses

I wrote:

> ID: the identifier of a word in the sentence **that corresponds** to the order of the word in the sentence, starting at 1 for each new sentence.

Can I replace "that corresponds" with "corresponding"? I ask it because "corresponding" itself has a different meaning, the question is the same about "that follows" and "following".

Comment: Yes you can. You can also say "The word's **ordinal position** in the sentence".

Answer (score 1):

> - ID: the identifier of a word in the sentence [that corresponds to X].

In general we can use participle clauses instead of relative clauses to post-modify noun phrases, if we want to. When we do this we don't include the Subject of the clause, and the verb must be a participle, not a tensed verb.

In the Original Poster's example, this means that we don't use the relative word *that* and we don't put in a new Subject for the clause. Because there is  no Subject, we use an *-ing* form of the verb:

- ID: the identifier of a word in the sentence [corresponding to X].

Notice that *corresponds* can be understood as a verb in both instances here. Using the participle form does not imply that the verb has changed its meaning.

Comment: Thank you, just as I repeatedly heard "corresponding" and "following" as adjectives, then I thought I may should say "that corresponds" ...

Answer (score 0):

First i think your sentence needs a main verb, from my understanding, "correspond" should take this role, so neither of your options can work, it should be "corresponds".

Besides, "corresponding to" and "correspond to" should share the same meaning. "Corresponding" is different because it is a noun, not a verb, and it means communications between parties.

Therefore the issue is different from "follows"/"following".

Comment: The example given reads like a glossary entry - in cases like that, you don't need a main verb (it's written in "note-form", and it's basically implied that the entire thing means "The ID is the identifier[...]")